# Fortify Denial of Service: Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have below code

```
               //web config
                <add key="RegexPatternx" value="^[ a-zA-Z0-9\-\./:]+$"/>
                
                //Code
                var regexPattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RegexPatternx"];
                string referrerHost = "localhost.test:80/";
                // Set the regex pattern to validate the target and referrerHost 
                var regexItem = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);// Fortify issue line Denial of Service: Regular Expression 
                var targetHost = target.Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "");
                string[] urlParameters = { targetHost, referrerHost };
                foreach (var urlPart in urlParameters)
                {
                    if (urlPart != null)
                    {
                        var isRegexMatch = regexItem.IsMatch(urlPart);
                        if (!isRegexMatch)
                        {
                            _log.LogInfo(loggingContext, "Cannot redirect as the target site URL is Invalid.");
                            RedirectToErrorPage();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The above code is working fine but in fortify scan i am getting "Denial of Service: Regular Expression" issue and its priority is high. I googled but not getting the exact solution. Kindly help me in solving this issue.

Comment: I gone through many issues in stackoverflow and other forums but not getting the exact solution.  The issue is shown in "var regexItem" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some regular expressions take exponential times to evaluate when passed certain input. For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS

I am not familiar with the fortify tool, but apparently it detected the use of Regular Expression, and, being an automated tool, it cannot determine if the regular expression is safe or not, so it flagged the line.

The regular expression in your web.config seems OK, but apparently the tool cannot know that. So if you are sure that the regular expression you are using is safe, then you can ignore this issue, and configure fortify to ignore this line (if possible). It is common for such tools to flag false positives. The purpose of such flag is to point the human user's attention to that line for review, and not necessarily a problem with that line.

With that said, the regular expression you are using doesn't properly match URLs. For example it will flag a string like `-a/:/dd` as a valid URL when it's not.

You can check [UrlAttribute source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs) line 46 for an example of a regular expression that matches URLs or google URL regular expression. But make sure that the regular expression you are using doesn't take exponential time to execute which can cause denial of service to your application.

Comment: Thanks "Sherif Elmetainy", By reading wikipedia article you shared,I got some idea and make some changes in code.
                  
                   var matchTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RegexMatchTimeout"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    var regexItem = new Regex(regexPattern,RegexOptions.None, matchTimeout);

I added TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds in my code and made some tweaks to the code. After this chages i ran the fortify scan and it removed the issues from fortify scan. Thanks for the wiki link.